# Scala Regex pattern matching issue when using |

Tags: regex, scala

This is my example code.

```
object Patterns {
  val workingPattern = """^thisworks[\w]+""".r
  val problemPattern = """^(fail|error|bs|meh)[\w]+""".r
}                                                                                                                                                                           

object TestMaker {
  var works = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
  var needsWork = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
  var junk = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
  def add(someInput: String) = someInput match {                                                                                                                                      
    case Patterns.workingPattern() => works.update(someInput, true)
    case Patterns.problemPattern() => needsWork.update(someInput, true)
    case _ => junk.update(someInput, true)                                                                                                                                       
  }
}
```

When I call `TestMaker.add("thisworks1234")`, the string "thisworks1234" gets inserted into TestMaker's works set. It works as expected.

When I call `TestMaker.add("this_is_just_junk")`, the string "this_is_just_junk" gets inserted into the junk set - also as expected.

Here's the problem. When I call `TestMaker.add("fail1234")`, that string will also be inserted into the junk set. It should however be inserted into the needsWork set.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pZ0kR3/1 The regex is OK. The problem is in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a non-capturing group with the second regex:

```
val problemPattern = """^(?:fail|error|bs|meh)[\w]+""".r
                         ^^^
```

This is required because you are not referencing the captured value in your `case`.

Note that you can still use capturing groups within your patterns to ignore them later while `match`ing with `_*`:

```
case Patterns.workingPattern(_*) => works.update(someInput, true)
case Patterns.problemPattern(_*) => needsWork.update(someInput, true)
case _ => junk.update(someInput, true)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1cHqu6):

```
object Main extends App {
    TestMaker.add("this_is_just_junk")
    TestMaker.add("fail1234")
    println(TestMaker.needsWork) // => Set(fail1234)
    println(TestMaker.junk)      // => Set(this_is_just_junk)
}
object Patterns {
  val workingPattern = """^thisworks[\w]+""".r
  val problemPattern = """^(fail|error|bs|meh)[\w]+""".r
}  
object TestMaker {
  var works = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
  var needsWork = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
  var junk = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
  def add(someInput: String) = someInput match {                                                                                                                                      
    case Patterns.workingPattern(_*) => works.update(someInput, true)
    case Patterns.problemPattern(_*) => needsWork.update(someInput, true)
    case _ => junk.update(someInput, true)    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works (of course!). Will accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Glad to help, just added a full demo with an alternative solution.